# Getting physical units of MolarGasConstant

Tags: units, physical-constants

I want to be able to get the MKS units and value of the molar gas constant $R$.  If I enter `Quantity["MolarGasConstant"]`, *Mathematica* returns $1R$, which is quite useless for my purposes.  I can easily look up the information elsewhere.  What I want *Mathematica* to tell me is that $R=8.31\; \text{J}/(\text{mol}\cdot K)$. Assume that I don't remember the specifics of this constant, such as its units.

I used to be able to get this kind of information from *Mathematica*.

Comment: Try `UnitConvert@Quantity["MolarGasConstant"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days a great place to start is Wolfram|Alpha:

[image]

But to answer your direct question:

```
UnitConvert@Quantity["MolarGasConstant"]
```

Then convert the output to SI or Metric units:

```
UnitConvert[
Quantity[8.31446, ("Kilograms" ("Meters")^2)/(
"Kelvins" "Moles" ("Seconds")^2)], "SI"]

UnitConvert[
Quantity[8.31446, ("Kilograms" ("Meters")^2)/(
"Kelvins" "Moles" ("Seconds")^2)], "Metric"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As Carl notes, you can express the gas constant in terms of base SI units with

```
r = UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "MolarGasConstant"]]
   Quantity[8.31446, ("Kilograms"*"Meters"^2)/("Kelvins"*"Moles"*"Seconds"^2)]
```

and then use `QuantityMagnitude[]` to extract the number, or `QuantityUnit[]` to extract the unit:

```
{QuantityMagnitude[r], QuantityUnit[r]}
   {8.31446, ("Kilograms"*"Meters"^2)/("Kelvins"*"Moles"*"Seconds"^2)}
```

To check that the resulting unit is compatible with $\rm{J}/(\rm{mol}\cdot\rm{K})$, you can have `UnitDimensions[]` perform the decomposition into base quantities along with the associated exponents:

```
UnitDimensions["Joules"/("Moles" "Kelvins")]
   {{"AmountUnit", -1}, {"LengthUnit", 2}, {"MassUnit", 1},
    {"TemperatureUnit", -1}, {"TimeUnit", -2}}

UnitDimensions[("Kilograms"*"Meters"^2)/("Kelvins"*"Moles"*"Seconds"^2)]
   {{"AmountUnit", -1}, {"LengthUnit", 2}, {"MassUnit", 1},
    {"TemperatureUnit", -1}, {"TimeUnit", -2}}
```

or just attempt to perform a conversion with `UnitConvert[]`, which also yields the conversion factor in the process:

```
UnitConvert[("Kilograms"*"Meters"^2)/("Kelvins"*"Moles"*"Seconds"^2), 
            "Joules"/("Moles" "Kelvins")]
   Quantity[1, "Joules"/("Kelvins"*"Moles")]
```